# Why null key is not allowed in TreeMap?

Tags: java, collections, red-black-tree

I am trying to understand the concept behind Java Collection framework and came along to this question - Why null key is not allowed in TreeMap?

Its giving NullPointerException if we try to add null key in TreeMap.

Tried to google the Internal Working of TreeMap and found something like TreeMap uses RedBlack tree algorithm which is difficult to understand for me right now and I am working on it.

> TreeMap is a Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation.In other
>   words , it sorts the TreeMap object keys using Red-Black tree
>   algorithm.

Please clear me, While other two implementation of the Map interface allows null as a key, then why TreeMap is not allowing to add null as a key?

I would like to thanks for explanation in advance.

Comment: How would you sort a `null` value?

Comment: Related - [Make treemap tolerate null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597061/make-treemap-comparator-tolerate-null)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`TreeMap` does allow null keys. The default *natural ordering* comparator is the one that throws the exception.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put(K,%20V)) of `TreeMap.put`:

> `NullPointerException` - if the specified key is null and this map uses natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null keys

The easiest way to allow null values is to create the `TreeMap` with a comparator like `Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())` or `Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())`

Comment: So, we just have to make Comparator accept the null and sort null key.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the same impression that `Treemap` does not allows any null key, but while using `java 6` I found I am able to add first element with `null` key in treemap, but with `java 8` it is not the case.

```
 Map<String, Date> productStartDatesBySourceProductID = new TreeMap<String, Date>();
```

[image]